# Delphi - TIdHTTP freezes when POSTing data

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe3, indy10, idhttp

I have an issue developing an HTTP client using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component.  I'm using Indy 10.5.9.0.

When I call the `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` method, the component freezes, and raises an exception:

> Connection closed gracefully

I already tried using the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method, but the same problem happens.

The problem doesn't happen using the `TIdHTTP.Get()` method.

Here is my code:

```
try
  jsonLatestFirmware := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(httpClient.Get(strGetLatest)) as TJSONObject;
  try
    srv := 'http://' + currentAlive.IP + ':9335/upgrade?command=start';

    sList := TStringList.Create;
    sList.Text := jsonLatestFirmware.get('data').JsonValue.ToString;

    fileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'finals\' + currentMACQR + '-' + currentAlive.IP + '.json';

    sList.SaveToFile(fileName);

    JsonRetorno := TStringStream.Create('');
    try
      JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create;

      WriteStringToStream(JsonToSend,TIdHTTPAccess(httpClient).SetRequestParams(sList, TEncoding.UTF8));
      JsonToSend.Position := 0;
      TIdHTTPAccess(httpClient).DoRequest('POST',srv,JsonToSend,jsonRetorno,[]); //component freezes here...

      strRetorno := TStringList.Create();
      strRetorno.LoadFromStream(JsonRetorno);

      lblInformacao.Visible := True;

      ShowMessage(strRetorno.Text);

    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + E.Message);
    end;

  finally
    sList.Free;
    JsonRetorno.Free;
    JsonToSend.Free;
    jsonResponse.Free;
  end;
except
  on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage('There are no firmwares available for this product.');
end;
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be calling `DoRequest` directly. I've never had a reason to do such a thing. What's the problem with just using `TIdHTTP.Post`?

Comment: `TIdHTTP.Post` happen the same problem. I had posted at the question, but it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Indy 10.5.9.0.

That is a very old and outdated version.  At the time of this writing, the latest version is 10.6.2.5455.  [Please upgrade](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx), as there have been a lot of changes and fixes to Indy since 10.5.9.

> When I call the `TIdHTTP.Post()` method, the component freezes, and raises an exception:

First, you are not calling `TIdHTTP.Post()`, you are calling `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()`.  You should be calling `TIdHTTP.Post()` instead, which calls `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` internally for you:

```
httpClient.Post(srv, JsonToSend, jsonRetorno);
```

Second, `Post()` can't freeze and raise an exception at the same time.  Which is actually happening?  How large is the JSON you are posting?  Does the server send any kind of response before the exception is raised?

Third, you *absolutely* should NOT be calling `TIdHTTP.SetRequestParams()` at all.  That method is meant for internal use by the `TStrings` overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` when it submits an HTML webform in `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` format.  That is NOT what you need in this situation.  You need to post your JSON as-is, not webform-encode it.

Indy uses blocking sockets.  Most operations in Indy are synchronous.  `TIdHTTP.Post()` is no different.  It blocks the calling thread until the HTTP post is finished.  If it freezes, that means the post is taking a long time to send, or the server is not sending a valid response back.  If `TIdHTTP.Post()` raises a "Connection closed gracefully" exception, that means the server has closed the socket connection on its end while `TIdHTTP` was still sending/reading data over the socket.  That could happen, for instance, if the server doesn't like your `POST` request, or if it determines the JSON is invalid while it is being received.

Also, your code can be simplified in general.  You are misusing `TStringList` for handling JSON data.

Try something more like this instead:

```
var
  sJSON, sRetorno: string;
  jsonLatestFirmware: TJSONValue;
  JsonToSend: TStringStream;
  ...
begin
  ...
  try
    sJSON := httpClient.Get(strGetLatest);
  except
    ShowMessage('There are no firmwares available for this product.');
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    jsonLatestFirmware := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(sJSON);
    try
      sJson := (jsonLatestFirmware as TJSONObject).get('data').JsonValue.ToString;
    finally
      jsonLatestFirmware.Free;
    end;

    JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(sJson, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      JsonToSend.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'finals\' + currentMACQR + '-' + currentAlive.IP + '.json');

      httpClient.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      sRetorno := httpClient.Post('http://' + currentAlive.IP + ':9335/upgrade?command=start', JsonToSend);
    finally
      JsonToSend.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: '#13#10 + E.Message);
    Exit;
  end;

  lblInformacao.Visible := True;
  ShowMessage(sRetorno);
  ...
end;
```